# Ajax não funciona - enviar dados PHP sem refresh

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, navegador-de-internet

Estou tentando enviar dados mesclados de um form + variáveis PHP para serem inseridos no BD, sem que haja refresh da página.

Para isso, tenho um form html simples, e uma condicional PHP que verifica o clique do submit desse form (isso por que tenho outros submits na mesma página). Dentro do IF, inseri meu AJAX para levar estes dados ao arquivo que gravaria no BD.

O form HTML:

```
<form id="textoResp" action="" method="post">
    <label for="textoResposta">Digite sua resposta abaixo:</label>
    <textarea name="textoResposta" required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="text" />
</form>
```

O trecho de PHP com o Ajax é:

```
<?php                   
    if(isset($_POST['text'])):
        $id_servico = $_GET['servico'];
        $id_sessao = $_GET['id'];
        $id_pergunta = $r['id'];
        $id_user = $_SESSION['usrid'];
        $texto = $_POST['textoResposta'];

?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function(){
            $("#textoResp").submit( function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'processa.php',
                    data:{ 'id_servico': <?php echo $id_servico; ?>, 'id_sessao': <?php echo $id_sessao; ?>, 'id_pergunta': <?php echo $id_pergunta; ?>, 'id_user': <?php echo $id_user; ?>, 'texto': <?php echo $texto; ?> },
                    success: function( data )
                    {
                        alert( data );
                    }   
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>                           
    <div class="status"><?php echo "Resposta Enviada!";?></div>                         
<?php
    endif;                  
?>
```

E o arquivo processa.php, que receberia os dados:

```
<?php

   $nid_servico = $_POST['id_servico'];
   $nid_sessao = $_POST['id_sessao'];
   $nid_pergunta = $_POST['id_pergunta'];
   $nid_user = $_POST['id_user'];
   $ntexto = $_POST['texto'];

   $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   mysql_select_db("db", $link);

   $sql1="INSERT INTO resposta(id_servico, id_sessao, id_pergunta, id_user, texto) VALUES ('$nid_servico', '$nid_sessao', '$nid_pergunta', '$nid_user', '$ntexto')";
   $executa_sql=mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());   

?>
```

O que acontece quando rodo esta página: os dados são preenchidos no bloco de código do Ajax no navegador, porém a página dá refresh (a linha "return false;" seria para impedir o refresh), e aparentemente os dados não chegam até o PHP processa.php, pois não há gravação no BD e nem exibe alert dos dados pelo Ajax.
Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para que não de refresh na sua página faltou passar o parâmetro de evento, segue o código:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        $("#textoResp").submit( function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'processa.php',
                data:{ 'id_servico': <?php echo $id_servico; ?>, 'id_sessao': <?php echo $id_sessao; ?>, 'id_pergunta': <?php echo $id_pergunta; ?>, 'id_user': <?php echo $id_user; ?>, 'texto': <?php echo $texto; ?> },
                success: function( data )
                {
                    alert( data );
                }   
            });
        });
    });
```

Com isso espero resolver seu problema do refresh, porém creio que não irá funcionar, pois você precisa pegar os valores dos inputs do form com o jQuery ou javascript para passar como data no ajax, de uma olhada em: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/.

Abs.

Comment: sobre o refresh, já alterei para `e.preventDefault();` mas, como vc mesmo disse, não funcionou. Agora, não sei exatamente como devo usar o `serialize()`, pois não tenho só dados de form, mas pego todos os dados e os converto em variáveis do PHP (por que a maioria vem do bloco do PHP). Como poderia ser nesse caso?

Comment: Nesse caso, você poderia fazer de duas maneiras, a primeira maneira é mais simples. Você pode incluir campos `<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $variavel_php ?>'>` e fazer o serialize. A outra maneira, é você colocar as variáveis em um array e transformar em um JSON, e no arquivo javascript utilizar a função `getJSON()` do jQuery para pegar esses valores e após isso fazer a requisição ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Troca isso:
`<input type="submit" name="text" />`

Por isso
`<input type="button" id="envia" name="text" />`

E no `ajax` troca isso:
`$("#textoResp").submit(function()`

Por isso:

`$("#envia").on('click', function()`

Está acontecendo isso porquê está usando o `submit`.

---

### PHP

Troca esse `if`, por esse:

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`

Comment: se troco o type por button, aparentemente o PHP não entende que o form está definido (linha `if(isset($_POST['text'])):`). Percebo isso por que agora os valores dentro do Ajax deixaram de ser impressos no navegador, e não há gravação no BD (apenas o refresh parou).

Comment: Editei meu poste.

Comment: A troca não surtiu efeito... Além disso, talvez dessa forma eu não conseguirei indicar ações para os demais submits que tenho na mesma página. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Não, você pode fazer o que quiser...
Mano, desculpa. Eu errei o código jQuery. Corrigi o post, a linha estava errada no `ajax` que coloquei, confira de novo...

Comment: Tentei novamente, de duas formas: como vc sugeriu -> `$("#envia").on('click', function()` e também outra maneira -> `$("#envia").click(function()`... Mas nada ainda. Nem está preenchendo no navegador mais... Com o submit ele continua somente preenchendo os dados no navegador, mas dá refresh